# Adding button icon ExtJS

Tags: ext-js

i created grid panel using ExtJS with bbar button, the buttton appears to be similar with the background of the panel which makes it to resemble like plain text not really button. so i want to add icon to the button or give it different color. is that possible? how to do that?

[image: figure of the button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the icon class for your button.Just use

```
iconCls: 'your_css_class'
```

and add a css rule with this name

```
.your_css_class
{
background-image: url(youricon.png)
}
```

Example:

Button:

```
   {
     text   : 'Navigate',
     iconCls: 'nav',
     handler: function() {
                           do this and that...
                          }
   }
```

CSS Rule:

```
.nav {
background-image:url(http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/examples/shared/icons/fam/folder_go.png);
}
```